# Responder Objetc Array en Web Service XML-RPC

Tags: php, xml, webservice

Amigos, necesito que el Servicio Web XML-RPC que desarrolle responda un object Array(1) y lo que me responde es un objetc Objetc(1)

Lo que me responde es con la estructura:
Response object Object(1) - filter: 
0 String(1) : "2"
[image: Lo que me response]

Y lo que necesito es:
Response object Array(1) - filter: 
0 String(2) : "03"

[image: Respuesta Esperada]

Esto lo pude ver con la extension de Google Chrome XML-RPC Client [Link Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xml-rpc-client/mbelaappiaalhoceejaopcghdlnhhain)
El codigo del WS es el siguiente:

```html
<?php
include 'xmlrpc.inc';
include 'xmlrpcs.inc';
function Suma ($xmlrpcmsg) {
    $uno = $xmlrpcmsg->getParam(0)->scalarval();
    $dos = $xmlrpcmsg->getParam(1)->scalarval();
    $resultado = $uno+$dos;
    $xmlrpcretval = new xmlrpcval(array(new xmlrpcval($resultado, "string")),"struct");
    $xmlrpcresponse = new xmlrpcresp($xmlrpcretval);
    return $xmlrpcresponse;
}

$servidor = new xmlrpc_server(array(
                    "ejemplo.Suma" =>  array( 
                    "function" => "Suma", 
                    "signature" => array(array($xmlrpcInt, $xmlrpcInt, $xmlrpcInt)), 
                    "docstring" =>  'Resultado suma'
                    )));                              
?>
```

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, creo que tienes un pequeño *lio*: Los *Array* **no tienen claves alfanuméricas**, son solo una secuencia de cosas: `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` es un *Array*. `{ hola: 1, adios: 2 }` es un *Object*.

Comment: @Trauma tengo claro la diferencia entre ambos, lo que no se como hacer es que me responda en la estructura object Array, como lo coloque en las imagenes. Edite las imagenes para ver si queda mas claro